# Spring and Ignite integration on different nodes

Tags: java, spring, cluster-computing, ignite

Consider this situation:

`Spring` application starts `Ignite` node which joins some ignite cluster. On this node starts ignite singleton service with `@SpringResource` injected in it (and according to ignite documentation this variable must be marked as `transient`). Now this node goes down and copy of the service is restored on a different `Ignite` node which doesn't know anything about Spring.

So the question is: **how to inject spring bean into this restored service?**

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your bean to the service's constructor and record it to a non-transient field. You should make sure that this bean is serializable and it doesn't depend on anything Spring-related (including annotations if you don't have Spring on the classpath of the second node). Otherwise Ignite won't be able to deploy your service and deserialise it on a different node.

Comment: thx, I thought of that. But I hoped that there were some internal ignite mechanisms for such tasks, something like proxy which would discover spring application and request bean from it?

Comment: @NoMercy You can force service to be deployed on a node with Spring. You can specify a node filter with ServiceConfiguration#setNodeFilter and check some condition in that filter. For example, you can prefix names of all  spring nodes with some specific string and check for it. It will look like this: 
cfg.setNodeFilter(ignite.cluster().forPredicate(/* your predicate */).predicate());

In this case SpringResource annotation will work for all instances of the service.